# Why does this template specialization fail when using a default parameter on the second invocation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates

```
struct MyStruct
{
    MyStruct() {}
};
struct MySndStruct
{
    MySndStruct() {}
};

template <typename T> 
T Func(const T& t = T()) 
{ 
    T ret;
    return ret;
}

template <> 
MyStruct Func<MyStruct>(const MyStruct& ms)
{
    MyStruct ret;
    return ret;
}
int main()
{
    Func<MySndStruct>();
    Func<MySndStruct>(); // Works

    Func<MyStruct>();
    Func<MyStruct>(); // Fails
    Func<MyStruct>(MyStruct()); // Works fine
    return 0;
}
```

The second invocation of the MyStruct specialization for Func fails with the following error in Visual C++ 2010

```
error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from 'MyStruct *' to 'MyStruct &
```

If I pass by value instead of by reference (`MyStruct Func<MyStruct>(MyStruct ms)`) the error becomes

```
fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
```

Is this a bug in Microsoft's c++ compiler or is default parameters not supported with template specializations?

If anyone can explain to me whats happening here, for instance, why does the compiler assume a pointer is passed in when it's IMO clearly not? And why does the first invocation work? I assume it has something to do with instantiating the template, but I'd like to know more precisely.

**EDIT:** Updated parameters to be const to highlight that this does not make a difference on Visual C++ 2010.

Comment: First error `(T& t = T())`. You cannot bind temporary to reference by standard. Code compiles fine on gcc after fix this: http://liveworkspace.org/code/1b8fecded33ebc25a6eb8519c6a083ea

Comment: Thanks ForEverR. The fix you suggested does not work with Visual C++ 2010. Would this imply it's a bug in the compiler?

Comment: Don't works for me in MSVC 2010, but works well in MSVC 2012 RC.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply ForEveR. Good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

replace `T Func(T& t = T())` with `T Func(const T& = T())` and it shall compile fine.

Comment: MSVC is cunning. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508607/rvalue-to-lvalue-conversion-visual-studio

Comment: Adding const to the parameter gives exactly the same error. Perhaps I should have mentioned that in the original question, but it's irrelevant so I left it out.

Comment: sorry, not for me (using gcc 4.7.0). So I cannot help here ... But you should have asked the question with the `const`.