# GCC constant temporary in binary expression

Tags: c++, gcc

Consider the following code:

```
struct A {
    A& add( int i ) { return *this; }
};

A& operator+=( A& a, int i ) { return a; }

void f() {
    A a1 = A().add( 1 ); // expr 1
    A a2 = A() += 1;     // expr 2
}
```

Both expressions 1 and 2 are accepted by VC. Expression 2 is rejected by GCC with "No viable overloaded '+='". However such an expression is accepted for operators taking a reference to constant object:

```
const A& operator+=( const A& a, int i ) { return a; }
```

Why does GCC force this temporary to be constant in the operator context when not in the method call context, and is this correct behavior?

Comment: turn up the warning level in MSVC and it will tell you the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A();
```

Creates temporary.

```
A& operator+=( A& a, int i ) { return a; }
```

temporary cannot be binded to `reference`. MSVC accept this, since it's non-standard extension. Look at [rvalue to lvalue conversion Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508607/rvalue-to-lvalue-conversion-visual-studio)

Comment: i'm not sure I'd call it a bug since MSVC emits a warning that this is officially undefined.

Comment: As for why the first expression is valid, C++ allows non-constant member functions to be called on temporaries.