# How std::move can work with copy-constructor that takes non-const reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, lvalue-to-rvalue

I was reading about std::move. Based on quite few materials, I concluded that std::move is just a function that converts its argument type to the rvalue-reference.

I also read that, rvalue-references can be used with the functions that take their arguments as const-references. This is meaningful because the contents of the objects guaranteed to be not changed.

To verify these ideas, I made a very simple experiment with a class located below.

I have created an object **t1** and used *std::move* to convert it to *rvalue-reference* and tried to create another object **t2** with calling copy-constructor.

The mysterious part is that even if I don't provide move-constructor, it works with the copy-constructor which I intentially defined its parameter as non-const reference.

However, if std::move converts type of **t1** to rvalue-reference, how compiler can bind it to the lvalue-reference?

Btw, I am using "Microsoft (R) Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Version 11.0.50727.1".

Could you please explain what I am missing here?

Thank you very much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Trace {
    public:
        Trace() {
        }

        // @1
        Trace(Trace& t) {
            cout << "trace::trace(&)" << endl;
        }

        // @2
        Trace(Trace&& t) {
            cout << "trace::trace(&&)" << endl;
        }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    Trace t1;

    // Calls @2 if it exists, otherwise calls @1 
    Trace t2(std::move(t1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: MSVC lets you bind rvalue expressions to non-const lvalue references, this is a non-conforming *feature*

Comment: time to switch to a better compiler…

Comment: "std::move is just a function that converts its argument type to the *rvalue-reference*" is true, but not useful for learning. A more useful statement would be "`std::move` unconditionally turns anything into an **rvalue**."

Comment: @NickyC into an *xvalue* to be pedantic

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki That's true and useful, but confusing and... pedantic.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant gcc, clang and MSVC all have their fair share of weird behaviour in language modes that enable extensions. And for all of them, the default is to allow extensions. For MSVC, `/Za` to deactivate language extensions, but there unfortunately are more flags that influence the non-standard behaviour.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, Thanks, with /Za flag, above code causes compile time error now.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Thanks, with your clue, I have found a similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508607/rvalue-to-lvalue-conversion-visual-studio

Comment: This code definitely is not standard conforming and should not compile.