# Does it work when a reference refers to a function's return value?

Tags: c++, return-value, return-value-optimization

```
class AA {
private:
    string s = "asd";
public:
    string func1() {
        return s;
    }
    string& func2() {
        return s;
    }
};
```

`func1()` returns a copy and `func2()` returns a reference.
And calls are like

```
AA a;
auto &r1 = a.func1();
auto &r2 = a.func2();
```

Both work fine after I test them.
But here is my doubt.
`r2` refers to `AA::s`; I get it.  But does `r1` refer to `AA::s` too? Or `func1`'s anonymous return value?
If the former, how does `func1` do it?  RVO?

Comment: func1() returns a copy of the string s (temporary), and r1 references this temporary.
func2() returns a reference to the original string s, and r2 references the original string s.
func1(), as the reference r1 will become a dangling reference once the temporary returned by func1() goes out of scope. In this specific example, since func1() returns a copy, it's not an issue. However, if func1() returned a reference to a non-static member variable of the object (which would be dangerous), it could lead to undefined behavior if the reference is used outside of its scope.

Comment: `auto &r1 = a.func1();` doesn't compile: https://godbolt.org/z/s4T1K3qjE

Comment: If it compiles (it shouldn't, but Visual C++ will do it) `r1` refers to a nonexistent object and only appears to "work" through the nature of undefined behaviour. (You can't determine the absence of undefined behaviour by testing.)

Comment: @molbdnilo msvc supports r-value to l-value conversion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508607/rvalue-to-lvalue-conversion-visual-studio

Comment: `const auto &r1 = a.func1();` is legal. And it's not UB because it extends the lifetime of the returned object.

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, unfortunately it does. It still does not extend the lifetime of the temporary, though.

Comment: `Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary object or to a subobject thereof, the lifetime of the temporary object is extended to match the lifetime of the reference ` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio (CL.EXE), I recommend using the `/permissive-` flag to disable Microsoft's extensions and alterations to standard C++, rather than using Microsoft's non-compliant C++.  (I make a similar recommendation for GNU's GCC's `g++` and LLVM's `clang++`.)

Comment: @Rodney, you're overlooking "_if the reference is lvalue reference to a non-volatile **const-qualified type** or rvalue reference_" that precedes that quote and applies to it.  `r1` and `r2` are _not_ const-qualified here.

Comment: Compiles fine when `const` is added: https://godbolt.org/z/3fqPcsfW4

Comment: @TobySpeight the comment was a follow up to the previous comment in which I added `const` to `r1`. It doesn't apply at all to `r2`. I am curious to know whether with the VS extension others have mentioned, the lifetime is also extended for non-const. If not then this extension would just pointlessly enable broken code.

Answer (score 1):

> Both work fine after I test them

No, the former `auto &r1 = a.func1();` isn't **legal**/valid C++ since `func1` returns **by value** and since *placeholder type deduction* uses the rules for template argument deduction. This means that the situation/problem is similar to the problem as if you were to write:

```
template<typename T> void deducefromauto(T &t);
deducefromauto(a.func1()); //won't work because non-const lvalue reference can't be bound to rvalue
```

And this won't work as a non-const lvalue reference can't be bound to an rvalue.